# CentOS 7 minimal doesn’t get an IP address from DHCP on startup

Tags: linux, centos, dhcp, centos-7

I had install CentOS 7 minimal. The interface `eno1677736` is up without an IP address when the OS starts up.

I restart the interface and it can obtain IP from DHCP server if I run this command:

```
ifdown eno1677736; ifup eno1677736
```

But if I reboot the OS, interface will lose the IP address.

My question is how to make the interface have an IP address automatically?

I tried configuring DHCP client [as explained here](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-dhcp-configuring-client.html).

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59789/how-do-i-configure-the-network-interfaces-persistently-in-centos-so-it-will-surv Have you tried it this way?

Comment: @DylanRz No, that way will use static ip address. But I must use ip from dhcp server.

Comment: That interface name does not look right.  Why is it so long?  Was that auto assigned by centos or manually based on some organizational standard?

Comment: @Xalorous it's assigned by centos. I just use a VMware Fusion vm.

Comment: Oh, ok.  I'm still adjusting to the consistent device naming, expecting some other sort of string.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check that `ONBOOT` is set to `yes` in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eno1677736`.

And a quick fix in case it already is—although not the best one—would be to add `ifdown eno1677736; ifup eno1677736` at the bottom of `/etc/rc.d/rc.local`.

Then save the file and make it executable:

```
chmod +x /etc/rc.d/rc.local
```

Now you’ll be running that command on every startup.

Comment: Oh, I have double check the `ONBOOT` before I ask. However I still left it `no` which I thought as `on`